# Deleting all number characters in a MS Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I tried to remove all of number characters that exist in a Word document, however, my code is useless because it is too slow, the problem is that I use `Document.Characters` to enumerate through characters, but it takes a lot of time to enumerate through every character in a document.

**So my question is:**
Is there any fast way of enumerating through and manipulating all characters in a Word document?

**Here is my code:**

```
    Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(path);
    object obj = Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter;

    foreach (Word.Range range in doc.Characters)
    {
        char c = range.Text[0];

        if (c >= 0x30 && c <= 0x39)
        {
            range.Text = "";

            Console.WriteLine("Removed {0}", c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to look at every character to determine if the character is a number.  So mathematically I see no way to optimize the algorithm.  There's the off chance that the .NET code is outdated or has a quicker function in the lib...just doubtful.  Have you considered pre-processing or parallel processing multiple pages/documents?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this library, but do you have the Word document open during this operation?  If so you may want to hide changes until you are complete with your editing `wordApp.Visible = false` and/or  `wordApp.ScreenUpdating = false"`;

Comment: @Harrison, the word application is not visible by default, and was not visible at testing.

Comment: If the doc files you are in the docx format; you could extract out document.xml file.  Then scan though the xml (<w:t> tags I think) directly.

Comment: For the specific problem you describe, using the Word object model to do the work is probably the fastest - i.e. use a suitable .Find object to replace "^#" by "". If you have to deal with digits from different scripts, and/or digits inserted using Word field codes such as { SYMBOL }, or have to report every replacment as in your example,  that's a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

So far, there is a workaround that I would use.
I would convert my document to a temporary text file, then make changes on that text file, then replace the whole document with the result and delete the file.